# Internet Connection state is blocked in MIUI

Tags: java, android, service, android-broadcastreceiver, internet-connection

Internet Connection state is blocked  for my long running background service in Xiomi phones. I am using BroadcastNetworkReciver for check internet connection.

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1560788/how-to-check-internet-access-on-android-inetaddress-never-times-out

Answer (score 1):

1. Open the Security app on your device
2. Click on DATA
3. Click on Restrict Data Usage
4. Now it will show you the app list.
5. Just scroll to that app on which you are wishing to block internet.
6. Click on Green Check Mark (it will get Red that means blocked)

For more information go with below link:

- http://www.androidbeat.com/2014/08/use-permissions-manager-miui-deny-access-permissions-apps/
- http://www.androwide.com/2016/08/turn-off-data-wifi-any-app-xiaomi-redmi.html